# How to use in ObjectiveC project C++ files

Tags: iphone, c++, objective-c, c, include

I have a reqular objective C project. I import 10 C++ files into my project. All this files take "are communicating" with each other. If I have a look at File1.h, this file can manage all the operations in other class.

So, the question is How to include reference to File1.h and to call functions from it.
For example: `[File1Class getAudioData];`
If I include it by `#include "File1.h"`, I will get a error "Class is unknown element"

P.S. I want to import [aurioTouch2](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/aurioTouch2/Introduction/Intro.html) sample code to my project and to call functions from theire C++ code.

Comment: The ending of the files is .cpp I'm guessing? For them to work in Objective-C you need to rename them to .mm. At least that's for mixing C++ in Objective-C.

Comment: But these files have Class declaration, you can't use it in .mm file , I think. And yes, its C++ files

Comment: Have you tried it already? With the '.mm' extension I mean.

Comment: I've tried, I renamed one of cpp files with Class declaration to .mm. And never the less, I see error in this .mm file "Class is unnkown element"

Comment: ...strange...sorry, can't quite help you then...

Comment: OK, you were right. I just renamed ViewController.m to .mm in addition, and now it works. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can simply open both the projects in Xcode and drag and drop the files you need from the aurioTouch2 application. Make sure the files are actually copied by selecting the check mark that you get after you drop the files in your xcode project. After this, you will be able to use those files/classes. Consider using ".mm" as the extension of the implementation file in which you want to use the c++ files/classes. You may also use ".mm" as extension for your appdelegate implementation file in case you get c++ related errors.

Comment: I just renamed ViewController.m to .mm in addition, and now it works. ViewController.m uses my .cpp files